# How to add alternate elements to a String array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a String - "Hello@World@Good@Morning"

I want to add alternate words to a string array. Example, from the above string, i should add only Hello and good to my new array.

```
for (String s   : StringsTokens) {
            myStringArray = s.split(Pattern.quote("@"));

        }
```

How do i add only alternate elements to string array.

Comment: Could you please share your code as [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Alternate elements are elements that have an index `i` such that: `i%2 == 0`....

Comment: use a ```for (int i = 0 ; i < SringsTokens.lenght ; i++) { // do your test here : if(i%2 == 0) then add the element to your array```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the patter you need to add words located at even positions.

So after splitting the string with the below code, to get a string array:

```
String[] words = string.split("@");
```

And initialising an ArrayList to use in your loops:

```
ArrayList<String> arList = new ArrayList<>();
```

you will run a `for` loop with :

```
for (int i=0 ; i<words.length ; i+=2) {
     // store the words in ArrayList like
     arList.add(words[i]);
}
//Convert ArrayList to Array and re-initialise ArrayList for the next String
String[] newArray = arList.toArray();
arList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] src = "Hello@World@Good@Morning".split( "@" );
        for ( int i=0 ; i < src.length ; i++ ) {
            if( i%2 == 0 ) {
                result.add( src[i] );
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
```

> > output: [Hello, Good]